# Projection matrix is not aplied in pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, matrix, pyglet

I'm trying to follow the OpenGL programming guide (AKA red Book)
But i'm using pyglet 1.2 (because I must use Python for a HighSchool project and I prefer python 3.4)

So I'm trying to make [the first example of the chapter 3](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) working

I tried to make my code the most close to the example:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

def cube(x, y, z, size):
    vertices = (GLfloat * 24) (*[x, y, z,
                                 x, y + size, z,
                                 x, y + size, z + size,
                                 x, y, z + size,
                                 x + size, y, z,
                                 x + size, y + size, z,
                                 x + size, y + size, z + size,
                                 x + size, y, z + size])

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices)

    indices = (GLubyte * 24) (*[0, 1, 2, 3,
                                4, 5, 6, 7,
                                0, 1, 5, 4,
                                7, 6, 2, 3,
                                0, 4, 7, 3,
                                1, 5, 6, 2])

    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices)
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)

    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
    glScalef(1, 2, 1)

    cube(50, 50, 0, 100)
    glFlush()

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) (width), (GLsizei) (height) )
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1.5, 20)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)
pyglet.app.run()
```

As you can see, due to the absence of glut I had to make my own cube function

So the problem here is that only the ModelView Matrix is aplied
Only a square with the `glScalef` method aplied on it show up

[image]

I tried to move the change of the Projection Matric in the `on_draw` method
It make just the square disapear

[image]

I tried also to use the `glFrustum` to change the model view matric,
That did not change anything

[image]

If somebody know where does this error come from,
I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: How are you setting up your matrices? Also there's no reason to call `glFlush`; use `SwapBuffers` (or whatever pyglet calls it) instead.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo What do you mean by setting up matrice?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thank's for the tip